# Problemas para extraer tgz.tg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

Estamos en la elaboración de un proyecto, debemos instalar la extensión de Solr para Apache, el problema es que no hemos podido extraer este mismo.

[image: Varios intentos fallidos de extracción]

Ya se ha intentado moviendo el archivo en otra carpeta y nada

¿Existe solución? Se agradece su ayuda

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: creo que tu pregunta seria mejor recivida en: https://superuser.com/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ o https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Ni idea por qué tienen un tgz.gz. Acabo de descargar el binario del [sitio oficial](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/solr/solr/9.0.0/solr-9.0.0.tgz?action=download), es un archivo tar gz común y corriente y con `tar -xvf` extrajo normal. Posiblemente está dañado o descargó incompleto. Validen el archivo usando el checksum sha512 que ofrecen